# How do I embed some HTML from a model into the page using Razor in MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to show an image but I have HTML like this (base 64 string truncated for brevity)

```
<p><img alt="downloadjpg" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxQTEhUSEhMVFRQWFxUWFxQVFxgUFBcVFRQWFxQVFxYYHCggGBolHBUVITEhJSkrLi4uFx8zODMsNygtLisBCgoKDg0OGxAQGywkICQsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLP/AABEIALEBHAMBEQACEQEDEQH/xAAbAAACAwEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAEBQIDBgEAB//EAEIQAAEDAgUBBgMGBAQEr6U/uvtJbpI4/Zf41f7jQH730kyvDeYeyf1rknGRxfPvRL39oPaG4ryI/A3/ALjUnoJJ6Spnf4/Sl/1QTK8Z5vhQL96EesHwvkX/AHzT1+/Ii9zemSJ//9k=" title="downloadjpg" class="img-responsive">aaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
```

I'm putting that HTML in a label:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmailBody, Model.EmailBody)
```

The image is not displaying. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is : Your base64 Image code is wrong Please check it again

> How to test, copy your src and past in browser or
>   Use this link encode your Image [Encode image based64](http://www.dailycoding.com/utils/converter/imagetobase64.aspx)

**Try this code it's working**

```
<div>
        <p>Taken from wikpedia</p>
        <img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
    AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
        9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
    </div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hpP45/)

Or

```
@Html.RAW(Model.EmailBody)
```

Comment: @Html.RAW(Model.EmailBody) try this one

Comment: @mason - Thank you friend